# Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::getAttribute()

Tags: php, joomla

Hi i am using module for banners, but when i access banner module from Joomla backend i got page without css means only fields with white background, and when i put Error reporting to maximum i got this error. I am using Joomla 3.2 and module is for Joomla 1.7 to Joomla 3

> Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::getAttribute() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fleischportal/modules/mod_kbanners4sobipro/elements/sqlmultiselectx.php on line 45
>
> **Config:**
> Working on Local
> Joomla 3.2
> Php 5.4
> Mysql 5.5 >

Please help and Thanks

Comment: If the module is for Joomla 1.7 then you shouldn't be using is on Joomla 3.2. A lot of code changes have been made which is most likely why you're getting this error

Comment: but this is provided by Module company.
Compatible with Joomla 1.7, 2.5 and 3.0! written by Developer.
actually this is provided to me by my client and this module is working on Joomla2.5 so i think it could work for Joomla 3.2 with lil modifications.

Comment: @user2753272  `getAttribute()` is not a function.... `getAttributes()` nly available [Reference 1](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#JXMLElement) [Reference 2](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: but this function is used in many other extensions tooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PHP documentation of SimpleXMLElement (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php) there is no method getAttribute() for this class.

Try to use method attributes() instead (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Comment: If this answer helped you, give me +1 (clicking in the up arrow left to the answer) and also mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: But by using attributes function, problem is not solving...
and i see getattribute in many of the default joomla extensions.